# simulate click on drop where dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, simulate

This is my first time posting, and I wouldn't be posting if I hadn't researched for hours how to do this.

I want to drag and drop an item onto a div that triggers a click on the location where it was dropped. I got the part where it drags and whatnot, but am unable to trigger a click (simulated).

Please let me know if you can help! I'd love some peace of mind lol.

<3 Lara

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The best thing to do with your post is to add some html (follow the guidelines, by indenting your code 4 spaces) and then run a fiddle of your code. You can start here https://jsfiddle.net create an account and then post the fiddle url in your question! Hope this gets you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Call a function when the item is dropped:

```
<div ondrop="dropFunction(event)"></div>
```

In that function, you need to collect the mouse coordinates:

```
var x = event.clientX;     // Get the horizontal coordinate
var y = event.clientY;     // Get the vertical coordinate
```

And then trigger a click at those coordinates:

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```

The mouse coordinates created above are for where the cursor is on the screen. You may want to adjust these coordinates based on the shape of the object being dropped.